# Is it cheaper for an Australian to obtain a Russian visa in Cambodia than in Australia?

Tags: visas, russia, australian-citizens, price, cambodia

I'm considering including parts of Russia on my next big overseas adventure.

Russian visas are very expensive, at least for me at home in Australia. For a multiple entry business visa like friends recommend it works out over $500 `AUD`.

From experience I have learned that it's often, but not always, possible to obtain a visa for some countries, in a third country. The Chinese visas I bought in Laos were much cheaper than I would've had to pay in Australia for example.

But I'm having trouble finding information online about Russian visa prices in Cambodia.

On [the site of the Russian embassy in Cambodia](http://embrusscambodia.mid.ru/web/cambodia-en/visa-information), I can only find fees for Cambodians.

(Yes I realize Russia normally only issues visas to residents of the country in which they submit their application. In this case it turns out to be very easy to get a resident status in Cambodia that Russia will recognize for visa purposes.)

Comment: In the meantime I have emailed the consular section of the Russian embassy to Cambodia and am awaiting a response ...

Comment: Are single entry tourist visas just as expensive in Australia? In Europe you can arrange one for around 150 USD.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Now that I have the prices from the embassy in Cambodia, I'll add the ones from the embassy here in Australia to my answer for comparison.

Comment: Probably a question in its own right, but how do you get the "resident status" in Cambodia that you mention? +1 to both Q & A.

Comment: @mts: Feel free to ask as a new question and I will answer (-:

Comment: @hippietrail will do right now. will I need to be Australian citizen or does European do a as well?

Comment: I've read that it works for Americans so it should work for everybody.

Comment: See here: [How do I proof “legality of stay in Cambodia” for a Russian visa application?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73291/32134)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wow I got a reply from the consular section of the Russian Embassy to Cambodia already!

> For all types of visa for Australian citizens:
>
> Single Entry Visa
>   100 USD **7 business days processing**
>   200 USD **3 business days processing**
>
> Double Entry Visa
>   200 USD **7 business days processing**
>   335 USD **3 business days processing**
>
> Multiple Entry Visa
>   340 USD **7 business days processing**
>   600 USD **3 business days processing**

**** CAVEAT! ****

I've just noticed that the email they setd me does not make clear whether these prices are for tourist visas, business visas, or the same for both.

---

For comparison, here are [the fees from the Consulate General in Sydney](http://www.sydneyrussianconsulate.com/en/visa-section/fees-and-processing-time-schedules.html):

> Visa fees (AUD) for Australian citizens and processing time applicable
>   from 1 October, 2015:
>
> **Tourist single entry visa:**
>
> $ 150.00 – ten business days processing (~ $114 USD)
>   $ 300.00 – two business days processing (~ $229 USD)
>
> **Tourist double entry visa:**
>
> $ 300.00 – ten business days processing (~ $229 USD)
>   $ 510.00 – two business days processing (~ $389 USD)
>
> **Private, Business, Humanitarian, Study and Working single entry visas:**
>
> $ 150.00 – ten business days processing (~ $114 USD)
>   $ 300.00 – two business days processing (~ $229 USD)
>
> **Private, Business and Humanitarian double entry visas:**
>
> $ 300.00 – ten business days processing (~ $229 USD)
>   $ 510.00 – two business days processing (~ $389 USD)
>
> **Business and Humanitarian multiple entry visas:**
>
> $ 525.00 – ten business days processing (~ $400 USD)
>   $ 900.00 – two business days processing (~ $686 USD)

**So it seems to be a bit cheaper, but it could depend on fluctuations in the exchange rate. The greatest savings are made when obtaining a multiple-entry business visa. That's more than $100 cheaper.**

Comment: At least at European embassies, the visa purpose does not affect the Price, only the number of entries and processing time

Comment: Finnish embassy lists prices for Australian citizens. Multiple entry visa can be obtained as low as 150€, and single entry visa at 47€.  You don't have to be a Finnish resident to apply for visa in Finland (or at least FAQ in the website says so). http://www.vfsglobal.com/russia/finland/Detailed_Visa_Fees.html

Comment: @user46435 That's "embassy [of Russia] in Finland", not "Finnish embassy" [of Finland].