# Is there any way to obtain a Russian Visa outside of country of residence?

Tags: visas, russia, uk-citizens

According to [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/russia/entry-requirements), as a UK citizen I should apply for a Russian entry visa through the Russia Visa Application Centre in London or Edinburgh.

I have since learnt that I can add [Manchester](http://ru.vfsglobal.co.uk/) to that list.

Is there any way to obtain a Russian visa outside of the UK? My intended visit is for 1 week to St Petersburg and Moscow travelling overland if that helps.

Comment: Not sure about UK citizens (I’m German) but back in 2010 I applied for a tourist visa from Helsinki where I was an exchange student. I think, the restriction is not your nationality but your residency.

Comment: I am UK resident as well. But debating whether it is possible to get visa whilst travelling.

Comment: You might find an answer here: [How do I prove “legality of stay in Cambodia” for a Russian visa application?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73291/32134)

Comment: It will depend on the  policies of the visa application center you intend to use, and the type of visa, or other legal presence,  you have in the country where you are applying. It will probablly be simpler to apply in the UK as your country of residence.

Comment: Visa can't be issued very fast. Are you sure you have enough time to obtain visa not in UK?

Comment: @VMAtm I think the 1 week reference for length of stay, not when OP needs the visa.

Comment: Depends on the embassy. Some will only accept those who are either citizens or legal residents of the country. Where do you live atm?

Comment: I am resident in the UK @Crazydre but currently in Sweden. The plan is to either go to Helsinki and/or Tallinn next. I am suspecting I will have to abandon my efforts to get to Russia this time or fly back to the UK for a period of time to obtain the visa.

Comment: Why don't you just phone the consulate? Ask them about your specific situation. It is suggested [on the web](https://goingrus.com/info/ru/get-russian-visa/komu-nuzhna-viza-v-rossiyu#comment-152). Also, it seems that you need [(semi)permanent residency](http://www.kdmid.ru/cons.aspx?lst=cnslfunk&it=/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%20-%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B5.aspx) in the country where you apply for a visa

Comment: I got a Russian visa in November 2016 from the Stockholm Russian Visa Center even though I'm not a permanent resident of Sweden. As long as I remember they didn't ask for details of my (unexisting) residency in Sweden. The one problem though with Russian Visa Centres in Sweden is that they ask you pay using the Swedish bank transfer system (Bankgiro): you can't pay by card or cash, which can be a bother (I heard Forex and others can do such bank transfers with a small fee though, but I didn't try).

Answer (score 5):

["GosNIIAS"](http://www.kdmid.ru/cons.aspx?lst=cnslfunk&it=/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%20-%20%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%20%D1%83%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B5.aspx):

> Для оформления визы иностранный гражданин должен обратиться в российское консульское учреждение по месту своего постоянного проживания.
>   .
>   To obtain a visa a foreign citizen must apply to the Russian consulate in their place of permanent residence.

[Travel Visa Agency Limited](http://www.gotorussia.co.uk/Russia/visas_Russia.htm):

> German passport holders should apply for a visa to Russian Consulate in Germany (Exception for German passport holders with residence in the UK confirmed by a letter from German Embassy or by special inscription in their passports).

The information in the latter site seems far from comprehensive (or nationalities are treated more differently than I would expect) but the gist is, officially "Nyet".